Integrating AWS MWAA, dbt-core, astronomer-cosmos
I am trying to do the astronomer-cosmos package in AWS MWAA. The set up is fine and cosmos package is installed as mentioned in requirements.txt file.
I maintain the snowflake credentials in aWS secret manager. In dbt profile.yml, passing the connection parameter as the env_vars. I dont want to maintain credentials in Airflow connections.
profiles.yml
dbt_project:
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: snowflake
      account: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT') }}"
      user: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_USER') }}"
      password: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD') }}"
      role: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_ROLE') }}"
      database: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE') }}"
      warehouse: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE') }}"
      schema: "{{ env_var('SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA') }}"
      threads: 1
  target: dev

Below is my dag code:
from datetime import datetime
import os
from cosmos import DbtDag, ProjectConfig, ProfileConfig, ExecutionConfig, RenderConfig
from pathlib import Path

dbt_project_path = Path("/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/dbt_project/")



profile_config = ProfileConfig(profile_name="dbt_project",
                               target_name="dev",
                               profiles_yml_filepath="/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/dbt_project/profiles.yml",)


dim = DbtDag(project_config=ProjectConfig(dbt_project_path,models_relative_path="models/"),
                    operator_args={"install_deps": True},
                    profile_config=profile_config,
                    execution_config=ExecutionConfig(dbt_executable_path=f"{os.environ['AIRFLOW_HOME']}/dbt_venv/bin/dbt",),
                    schedule_interval="@daily",
                    start_date=datetime(2023, 9, 10),
                    catchup=False,
                    dag_id="dim",
                    render_config = RenderConfig(select=["+path:models/dim/dim.sql"]))

Now I need to pass the credentials for the env_var by accessing the secret manage. I used a python script to get those details. But i am struck how to map those env_variables to the dag
Tried using python script to fetch the values from the secret manager and set as environment variables. but profile.yml is not using it.

Are you using the airflow database or secret manager for connections

I am using secrets manager for maintaining the credentials. I don't want to expose the credentials anywhere.

Is airflow setup to use secret manager instead of the airflow metabase dB?

Issue resolved by adding below configs :

Clarify how you are setting the environment variables in your Python script and how you are running the script.

Issue resolved by adding below configs :
 project_config = ProjectConfig(dbt_project_path, 
                               models_relative_path="models/",
                               env_vars={"DBT_ENV_SECRET_USER": SNOWFLAKE_USER,
                                         "DBT_ENV_SECRET_PASSWORD": SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD},)

